# Elusive Stack Smashing error: why does my string_to_float function sometimes crash?

Tags: c, crash, legacy, stack-smash

I am working with some legacy C code running on a Raspberry Pi (3, I think) running arch linux.
As part of the app's start-up, it reads in a file line by line and stores each line to some custom structure.

99 times out of a hundred, this works fine and we all live happily ever after. In that odd one out, I get a *stack smashing detected* error, forcing a reset.

I've already verified that the lines are correct and consistently formatted.

I've narrowed it down to another function that gets called twice during the file parsing:

```
const char* num = "+-.0123456789";
const char* Mults = "pnumkMGT";

float engtof(char* s)
{
printf("engtof: %s\n",s);
    float f, g = 1;
    char m, *q = 0, w[32] = {0};
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) w[i] = 0; // clear w

    strcpy(w, s);
    for(q = w; strchr(num, *q) != NULL; q++);
puts(q);       // sometimes prints some garbage after the desired char
    if(*q == 'E' || *q =='e')
        return atof(w);

    if(*q != 0 && strchr(Mults, *q) != NULL)
    {
        m = *q;
        g = getMult(m); // behavior already verified
        *q = 0;
    }
puts(w);       // seems to reach here before sometimes stack smashing, but w still looks right...
    f = atof(w);
    f *= g;
    return f;
}
```

(Disregard the various printf and puts statements. Those are there for debugging, since we can't figure out how to get remote debugging from NetBeans 12.3 working)

This is supposed to take a string in engineering format (s = "{value}{multiplier for power of 10}{unit}") (s="xkV" or s="a.bcmA", for example) and convert it to a float value (x000 or 0.00abc in the examples). This gets called ~300 times during startup when everything works, but when it doesn't work we stack smash on the first call (usually with s = "0").

Everything I've found so far on stack smashing talks about buffer overflow and out-of-range indices, but as far as I can tell, neither of those apply here. Granted, my understanding of pointers is only so-so...

If it happened every time, I'm confident I could find the problem, but since it happens so rarely, I'm at a loss on why this is happening. Anyone have any insight on this?

EDIT:
Here's the function that's calling engtof during startup:

```
void loadCalFactors()
{
printf("loadCalFactors\n");
    FILE *fp;
    char s[120], w[80] = {0}, *p;
    int i, j;

    fp = fopen(fileCF, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        sprintf(s, "Can't open: %s\n", fileCF);
        printf(s);
        netWrite(s);
        return;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N_CALFACTOR; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        fgets(s, 80, fp);
//puts(s);
        p = strtok(s, ",");

        while(p != NULL)
        {
//puts(p);
            switch(j)
            {
                case 0:
//puts("Header");
                    strcpy(w, p);// header
                    j++;
                    break;
                case 1:
//puts("Gain");
                    calFactors[i].g = engtof(p);
                    j++;
                    break;
                case 2:
//puts("Offset");
                    calFactors[i].os = engtof(p);
                    j++;
                    break;
                case 3:
//puts("Unit");
                    strcpy(calFactors[i].unit, p);
                    j++;
                    break;
            }
//printf("j= %i, p= %s\n",j,p);
            p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
puts("loadCalFactors done");
}
```

It only ever seems to have a problem with the first call to engtof. If it gets past that, it goes all the way through the file just fine.

Here are the first few lines of fileCF:

```
Input Source 5V Range,0,0,V
Input Voltmeter 5V Range,0,0,V
Input Source -5V Range,0,0,V
Input Voltmeter -5V Range,0,0,V
Input Source 50V Range,0,0,V
Input Voltmeter 50V Range,0,0,V
Input Source -50V Range,0,0,V
Input Voltmeter -50V Range,0,0,V
```

And here's getMult:

```
float getMult(char m)
{
puts("getMult");
    float f;
printf("m=%c\n",m);
    switch(m)
    {
        case 'p': f = 1E-12; break;
        case 'n': f = 1E-9; break;
        case 'u': f = 1E-6; break;
        case 'm': f = 1E-3; break;
        case 'k': f = 1E3; break;
        case 'M': f = 1E6; break;
        case 'G': f = 1E9; break;
        case 'T': f = 1E12; break;
        default: f = 1; break;
    }
//printf("f=%g\n",f);
    return f;
}
```

In the interest of helping produce a MVE, here's all our includes:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
```

I don't know how many of these are even used in the sections shared above, and I'm sure none of them are being used to their full potential.

Comment: It would be easier for other people to help you if you could provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. Can you maybe create a function `main` which calls the function `engtof` in such a way that it is able to reliably reproduce the stack smash, for example by setting `s` to `"0"`?

Comment: Also need the `getMult` function, if you don't know the reason for failure then `// behavior already verified` may not hold. And the actual input you give it that causes the crash.

Comment: Perhaps symptomatic of undefined behaviour somewhere in the code. But "somewhere" could be anywhere, not necessarily in this code.

Comment: @WeatherVane It gets through the getMult function consistently with correct output. I DID mention that the input that usually crashes is "0", but it doesn't cause the crash consistently.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree that it's most likely undefined behavior, I just don't know how to track down where that's happening.

Comment: Sorry, but if you think this code causes the crash, then you must provide the code that is involved: all of of it.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel If I could reliably reproduce the stack smash, I doubt I would need to be here asking for help. As I mentioned, 99 times out of 100 (or so), this gets called ~300 times with no problem (with a vast majority of those having s = "0").

Comment: This has an obvious code smell to me given the symptoms:  `strcpy(w, s);`

Comment: Please don't keep arguing that we don't need to see `getMult()`.

Comment: Step 1: enable warnings and follow them up. There are some less important ones like freely switching between `float` and `double` values: these should have been dealt with and I wonder what other warnings there might be.

Comment: Wow, your code is unreadable. Use better names for your variables. One thing I noticed: in `engtof` the variable `w` has a fixed size. Then you use `strcpy(w, s);`. You never checked whether  `w` is large enough to contain the string pointed to by `s`. If the string is larger than 31 characters, you're going write beyond the bounds thus the undefined behaviour. You should use `strncpy`. I stopped looking at the rest of the code, because I got a headache.

Comment: @Pablo Welcome to my world for the last year! Just trying to wrap my head around this behemoth full of bad practices and spaghetti, but not having the time or expertise needed to refactor it. And all without the benefit of a debugger, 'cuz we can't figure out how to get it working... It also doesn't help that C\C++ is not my forte. I'm much better with Java and C#.

Comment: @Greenwiz29 oh boy, I'd recommend that you first start by changing the variables names, so that their purpose is clear to you just by looking at the variable name, without having to read the code. Then refactoring shouldn't been a problem, once you've understood the algorithm there.

Comment: @Greenwiz29: At least the read out of bounds should be easily reproducible, by simply calling the function `engtof` with the argument `"0"`. If the tool you are using to detect the "stack smashes" is unable to reliably detect this read out of bounds, then you may want to consider using a different tool to detect such errors. I have had very good experience with [AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), and as far as I can tell, it is able to detect the read out of bounds reliably, in your case. That tool is supported with gcc, clang and MSVC, and is free.

Comment: @Greenwiz29: Note however that using AddressSanitizer increases CPU and memory usage significantly. You should therefore only use it for debugging purposes.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Unfortunately, the guy who set up everything on the linux/Pi side of things (which includes gcc) is no longer here, and no one else here has any experience outside of Widnows, so changing/adding tools to out dev environment is a larger task than we currently have time for.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel For now, our debugging is limited to print statements and crash alerts via SSH. We've tried to follow a few guides on setting up remote debugging through Netbeans 12 (starting here: https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/compilers-and-ides/netbeans-windows/installing-netbeans-for-c-remote-development-on-a-raspberry-pi), to no avail.

Comment: @Greenwiz29: I believe in most recent versions of `gcc`, AddressSanitizer is included. All you have to do is add `-fsanitize=address` to the command line when compiling the program. Installing additional software will probably not be necessary.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I will have to see if I have access to the bash file that runs the compiler, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
for(q = w; strchr(num, *q) != NULL; q++);
```

will invoke undefined behavior if you call the function with `s` pointing to the string `"0"`. This loop will only terminate once `q` points to a non-null character that is not in `num`, which will not be the case until `q` points out of bounds of `w`.

If you want `q` to point to the first character in `w` that is not part of `num`, then you can use the following line instead:

```
q = w + strspn( w, num );
```

It is also possible to solve this (less efficiently) by calling `strchr` in a loop, as you have attempted. However, the correct way to do this would be:

```
for(q = w; *q != '\0' && strchr(num, *q) != NULL; q++)
    ;
```

Adding the expression `*q != '\0'` will prevent the pointer `q` from going out of bounds of `w` (assuming that the string has a null terminating character).

Comment: This is the cause of the `// sometimes prints some garbage after the desired char` and this is another reason to see what `getMult()` is doing next.

Comment: @WeatherVane The whole set of code after and including `strcpy()` looks sketchy, with lots of evidence of [Easter egging](https://www.definitions.net/definition/easter+egging), such as **both** `w[32] = {0};` and `for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) w[i] = 0; // clear w`.

Comment: I noticed that: the string being set up three times.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel How would you recommend fixing this or doing it better? C is not my forte.

Comment: @Greenwiz29: Please explain what that line is supposed to accomplish, then I can tell you how to fix it. Where do you want `q` to point after that line? Do you want `q` to point to the first character that is not in `num`? If that is the case, then it would be easier to use the function [`strspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn). You could simply write `q = w + strspn( w, num );`.

Comment: It looks as if the code intends to pick up the first non-number (or sign or point) such as in say "1K" and send the `'K'` to `getMult()`. But the failing input `"0"` doesn't have a multiplier. That's why I want to see `getMult()`, when it is being sent an unexpected value beyond the end of the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's right. Also, getMult is now at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Greenwiz29, Instead of that loop, consider `q = w + strspn(w, num)`.  Not only should it be more efficient, but it also has well-defined behavior when `w` contains only characters in `num`.

Comment: @Greenwiz29 thank you, it does seem OK, but the code you provide still has too much missing to be pieced together and compiled.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel That seems to have done it! I'll do more testing tomorrow, and if it's no longer randomly crashing, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @WeatherVane There's over 10k lines to all the code, and it's a big pile of spaghetti, so paring it down to a minimum viable example is no small task.

Comment: And that is exactly why. The act of preparing the [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can often lead you to the fault.

Comment: @Greenwiz29: I was able to create my own [mre] by simply creating a function `main` which does nothing else than call `engtof` with `s` pointing to the string literal `"0"`, and replacing the function call to `getMult` with the value `1.0`. I then ran that program using [AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) and I was immediately able to see that the buffer `w` was being read from out of bounds. Without a [mre], it would have been much harder for me to diagnose the issue. This shows how important it is to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: With `getMult()` defined to return 1 in the cases where the original `engtof()` function avoids calling it, the body of `engtof()` could be reduced to a three-line thin wrapper around `strtof()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What would that look like? I am all for cleaning up my codebase like that when I can figure out how.

Comment: @Greenwiz29, `float engtof(const char* s) {
    char *q;
    float num = strtof(s, &q);
    return num * getMult(*q);
}
`.  That relies on the fact that `strtof()` stops parsing when it reaches something that doesn't match the expected format, *and* (optionally) returns a pointer the character after the last one it accepted.  Note that there is no longer any need to make a copy of the string, either.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'll have to try that!

Comment: @JohnBollinger That works like a charm! If you'll add this an an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @Greenwiz29, but my suggestion -- as helpful as I hope it was --  does not actually answer the question that was posed here about why the original function sometimes crashed.  The above answer does.

Comment: @JohnBollinger True. Is there some other way I can give you some credit/reputation for your suggestion?

Comment: Don't worry about it, @Greenwiz29.